# Does $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ have a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ when $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, gaussian-integers

It seems well understood that $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ has non-trivial solutions in the integers. I found a parametrization of a class of solutions [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/016)
$$a=85v^2+484v-313 \quad\quad b=68v^2-586v+10$$
$$ c=2\sqrt{22030+28849v-56158v^2+36941v^3-31790v^4} \quad d=357v^2-204v+363$$
which still seems incomplete since one must search through values of $v$ to find one that yields a rational $c$ like $v = \frac{-31}{467}$ for example.

I'd like to find a solution in the $\textbf{complex numbers}$ - so in the Gaussian integers specifically - with the added condition that $a$, $b$, and $c$ have the $\textbf{same length}$. So
$$\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|\quad\text{for}\quad a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$$

I tried some substitution like
$$r=a+b+c \quad\quad s=ab+ac+bc \quad\quad t=abc$$
This yields
$$a^4+b^4+c^4=(r^2-2s)^2-2(s^2-2rt)$$
But unfortunately this new equation - though very interesting - isn't any easier to solve. Further, $r,s,$ and $t$ don't even preserve any information about the constraint $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|$

> Does there exist a non-trivial solution to $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|c\|$ and $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Given the complex number $a = p+q\,i$, by length do you mean its absolute value $|a| = \sqrt{p^2+q^2}$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yeah

Comment: Solving $a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4$ in the Gaussian integers is interesting and hard enough.

Comment: Yeah. The magic square of squares problem is related though. (http://www.multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquaresSearch.htm) Specifically, there is a transformation from solutions of $a^4+b^4+c^4\in \mathbb{R}, |a|=|b|=|c|$ (for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$) into a magic hourglass of squares.